# How to disable auth verification email send, from Wordfence?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, wordfence

In Wordfence documentation says:

"*The filter “**wordfence_ls_require_captcha**” can be used to disable the CAPTCHA in circumstances of your choice. This may be useful for plugins that contain REST endpoints with authentication that should not require a CAPTCHA. Your filter should return false to bypass the CAPTCHA requirement when necessary, or otherwise true when the CAPTCHA should be required*"

If I tried to make an API Call through **JWT**, I am getting an **auth verification link via email** and could not proceed to my flow. This API Call already has username:password for auth user. Thus, how could I use this filter

```
wordfence_ls_require_captcha
```

in order to **disable the auth verification mail** like Wordfence suggest in the documentation (email sent in the inbox, with verification link, in order to login - this is what I want to disable)?

*I already have installed a plugin that Disables all APIs Calls, for un-authorized users. So, this verification email is useless for now.

Comment: The question seems unclear to me. You say "how could I use this filter...in order to disable the auth verification mail like Wordfence suggest in his own doc...?". Wordfence docs you quoted above says that you can disable the CAPTCHA using that filter; it doesn't say you can disable the auth verification mail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the latest WordFence available version (7.5.5 at the time of writing) seems that the email with subject "Login Verification Required" is sent only under two conditions (AND):

- `$requireCAPTCHA = true`
- `$performVerification = true`

Since we can make `$requireCAPTCHA = false` using that filter, this is how you want to deactivate that email:

```
add_filter( 'wordfence_ls_require_captcha', '__return_false' );
```

Comment: ok @microbabini ! give some time to test your code! I have edited my question a little bit. I just want to disable the verification email Wordfence send, in order to login.. I did not know the syntax of this add_filter - hook. Thus, I will check it and let you know

Comment: The syntax is straightforward: the first param is the filter you want to hook to, the second param is the function you want to call (in your case, a simple callback which returns false, which is a common case in wordpress and there's a __return_false() function in core).

Comment: You are correct! Finally got this working..   
Now I could move on. thanks!